# How do I get my text wrapped in a P element when deselecting list in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have this html in an inline CKEditor.

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

If I use the list tool button, my P transforms into a list.

```
<ul>
   <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

But when I click the list button again, my text is left unformatted.

```
Hello
```

How can I get back the previous element, that was before the list?

Comment: Did you set `config.autoParagraph` to `false`?

Comment: @Reinmar Doesn't work without config.autoParagraph or explicitly setting it to true.

Comment: So you would need to create a sample, because this is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it is normal behaviour, that really helped me find the source to the problem. After boiling my code down to total minimalism, I found that the config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR is causing this behaviour.